# Yahoo web mail is stripping out certain inline email styles

Tags: html, css, html-email

Yahoo web mail (mail.yahoo.com) is stripping out these inline styles, but keeping things like color and padding.

```
text-decoration
font-size
border-radius
text-align
font-family
```

Any idea why these are purposely being removed?

Example:

```
<span style="font-size:30px;">Hello</span>
```

becomes:

```
<span style>Hello</span>
```

Comment: Your css, for whatever reason ,may not be compatible with yahoo mail so use this website to check: https://putsmail.com/ .

Comment: I tested sending email from gmail id to yahoo id. <span style="font-size:30px;">Hello</span> is working as expected. The inline styles are not stripped as you are claiming.

Comment: putsmail.com seems to let html through without getting tainted.  Maybe yahoo is blacklisting my domain and stripping out styles as a result?

Comment: Maybe your problem is the line length. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363580/simple-html-email-basic-css-styles-being-stripped

Answer (score -1):

**What can be done?**

This is the difficult part because options are few. Even with free market choices well established corporate entities have little to no business reasons to improve their products unless competition comes along. You could always attempt to file a bug report (*like, where if even any where though...*) and as usual wait decades for a(n intelligent) response (*cough* Mozilla *cough*). You *could* attempt to work around the issue (replace `width` with `min-width` in example). I've noticed that `font-size: 120%;` works just fine so consider what unit values you're using for testing.

You can make a different though, even if it's relatively small. I was wronged by a motherboard manufacturer in the mid-2000s and since then they've lost tens of thousands of dollars of sales because of me directly and who knows how much more based on the video I posted back then and that is just in the past ten years. The issue with Yahoo is different, at best all you can do is write a blog entry and link to other people talking about the issue to raise awareness. You could go so far as to disallow registrations from users with Yahoo accounts or greatly discourage users from using Yahoo accounts though that could lead to a loss of members so I wouldn't do something like that unless you've got something people really want. The state of HTML email in general is exceptionally sad at this point though most (at least technical users) typically have multiple email addresses.

You could always use `<style type="text/css"></style>` even though scoped CSS is *not* widely supported in 2017 except for Gecko/Firefox though it did seem to fix some of the issues for me that you mentioned you were having.

Lastly you can always provide a "view this email on our website" option; I see it all the time because HTML email is *still* a disaster (2017). I've even seen nonsense with developers sending email with `html` element (uh, it's not an entire page, it will be embedded, but you know, whatever...).

So try utilizing different unit values and even the contexts themselves. Inline-styling *is* the way to go and if that fails provide a website version of the email (with security considerations for email with sensitive data).